# How to trigger IBAction from UIButton in Storyboard static cell?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitableview, ibaction

I have a Storyboard with a `UITableViewController`.  In this controller, I have static cells where one of them is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.  In the IB I added a `UIButton` to this static cell and connected it to an `IBAction` in the `UITableViewCell` subclass.  However, the `IBAction` is never called.  Why doesn't this work?  How can I achieve the desired behaviour where a button inside a cell triggers an event through the IB?

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BSWorkoutsCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons;

- (IBAction)tapButton:(id)sender;
@end
```

.m

```
- (IBAction)tapButton:(id)sender{
    if (!_buttonsHidden){
        [self animateHideButtons:(UIButton *)sender];
        _buttonsHidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Images

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post the code where you connect your button to the code AND where the IBAction should get called

Comment: @CaptJak I do the connections through the IB.  The TouchUpInside event is connected to my - (IBAction)tapButton:(id)sender method.

Comment: Thats wonderful. Please edit your question and copy paste those methods into it. What do you mean "I do my connections through the IB". Do you have the properties declared in the appropriate .h file? please post the contents of the .h file where the properties are declared and the contents of the .m file where the IBActions are triggered.

Comment: @CaptJak I hope the edit makes it clearer.

Comment: Nice! I see now! So, you set a breakpoint at the IBAction and it doesn't trigger? Or is it just that nothing happens when you expect it to? Can you trigger your animation manually and you know your animation works?

Comment: @CaptJak I can trigger my animation manually.  I set the breakpoint at the IBAction and nothing happens.

Comment: @CaptJak It might be worth mentioning that the IBOutlets work as expected.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure... Is your `if` conditional complete? What does this accomplish? Do your buttons hide if not already hidden? Not trying to be a jerk, I'm just trying to understand. From what I see, it looks like something is missing in your `if` statement, which is making the result always turn out true.

Comment: @CaptJak First, I set the `_buttonsHidden = NO` in the constructor.  I also have breakpoints in the method and the first line of the `if` statement.  The debugger should stop in those breakpoints.  Even more so, there is no sign of the buttons being pressed in the UI even though they are marked with `User Interaction Enabled`.

Comment: I just answered my own question.  For some reason I had the cell's `User Interaction Enabled` set to false.  Now that I changed that, it works.

Comment: Make sure userInteractionEnabled is also checked for UITableView and the UITableViewCell and UIViews too if the buttons are subviews of UIViews in the tableView cells.

Comment: You can write your solution as answer, mark it as answered and close this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realised that the UITableViewCell had `User Interaction Enabled` unchecked in the IB.  This made any subviews inside it not interactive, thus the buttons not actually being pressed, and the `IBAction` not being called.

Once I checked the box, everything worked fine.